# On the definition of homotopy extension property

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm reviewing some material from the last semester, and in class we gave the following definition:

**Def. 1**
A pair $(X,A)$ of spaces have the **homotopy extension property** if for any homotopy $H: A \times I \to T$ such that exists $f: X \to T$ continuous, and such that $H(-,0)= f|_A$, then there exists $\tilde{H}:X \times I \to T$ that extends $H$.

From my understanding, that means that we also have that $\tilde{H}(-,0)=f$; but then we also said that an equivalent definition is

**Def. 2**
A pair $(X,A)$ of spaces have the **homotopy extension property** if there exists a continuous map $$r: X \times I \to X \times \{0\} \cup_{A \times \{0\}} A \times I,$$ where $\cup_{A \times \{0\}}$ denotes the pushout.

Given that I have may wrote down the definitions wrong, it seems to me that the two definitions are not equivalent, and in particular the second should be wrong, since for any homotopy $H: A \times I \to T$ such that exists $f: X \to T$ continuous, and such that $H(-,0)= f|_A$, following the second definition we'd not get a map $\tilde{H}:X \times I \to T$ with $\tilde{H}(-,0)=f$, but only a map $\tilde{H}:X \times I \to T$ such that
$$
 \tilde{H} \circ i_{X \times \{0\}}\circ i_{A \times \{0\}} = \tilde{H} \circ j_{A \times I}\circ j_{A \times \{0\}}, 
$$
where $i_{X \times \{0\}}: X \times \{0\} \to X \times I$ is the inclusion, and similarly for $j_{A \times I}: A \times I \to X \times I, j_{A \times \{0\}}: A \times \{0\} \to A \times I, i_{A \times \{0\}}: A \times \{0\} \to X \times \{0\}$.

Could someone please tell me if I'm right and/or clarify the definitions, or give me a more clear definition with the term "extends" properly explained? Thanks!

Comment: Note how to construct $r$ from definition 1: Take $T = X \times \{0\} \cup_{A \times \{0\}} A \times I$ and $H: A \times I \to T$ the inclusion map. Similarly $f: X \to T$ is given by $f(x) = (x,0)$. Then $r = \widetilde{H}: X \times I \to T$ is like in definition 2. However, $r$ has the additional property that $r|_{T} : T \to T$ is the identity, so it seems to me that what you should want in definition 2 is to add the condition that $r$ is a retraction.

Comment: Your equation does not make sense. The domains and codomains of those inclusions don't even match up.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch thank you for your help, but even with the condition for $r$ to be a retraction, showing $2 \Rightarrow 1$ doesn't seem trivial to me...

Comment: @Thorgott sorry about that, I've messed up with the notation; now it should be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the additional assumption that $r$ in Definition 2 needs to be a retraction, both definitions are equivalent:

Given $H: A \times I \to T$ and $f: X \to T$ such that $H(-,0) = f|_A$ allows us to define a map $H' : X \times \{0\} \cup_{A \times \{0\}} A \times I \to T$ which is $f$ on $X \times \{0\}$ and $H$ on $A \times I$. As both maps coincide on $A \times \{0\}$, this is well-defined.

In particular, if there exists a retraction $r : X \times I \to X \times \{0\} \cup_{A \times \{0\}} A \times I $, then we can define $\widetilde{H} = H' \circ r$ and note that $\widetilde{H}$ has the desired property: In fact we have$$\widetilde{H}|_{A\times I} = H' \circ r|_{A \times I} = H'|_{A \times I} = H$$ as well as $$\widetilde{H}|_{X \times \{0\}} = H' \circ r|_{X \times \{0\}} = f$$

This shows that if $(X,A)$ has the homotopy extension property with respect to Definition 2, then it also has the property with respect to Definition 1.

The other direction was already described in the comments: You take $T = X \times \{0\} \cup_{A \times \{0\}} A \times I $ and $H$ and $f$ to be inclusions $A \times I \to T$ and $X \times \{0\} \to T$, respectively. The resulting $\widetilde{H}$ is the desired retraction.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've just realized that my confusion was due a misunderstanding in the definition of pushout.